# How do i always start a defined value in a select html element

Tags: select, jquery-select2

I have predefined range values as options of a select element  the ranges can be from any negative values to a predefined positive (I am using the select2 plugin).

For instance -12  to +12 at a defined increment say 0.25 in this case How do i get the option values to always start at  0.

```
<select id="form_exam:currentLenses:rCylinder" name="form[exam:currentLenses:rCylinder]" class="select-2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="form_exam:currentLenses:rCylinder" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option value="" data-select2-id="24">
        </option>
        <option value="-12.00" data-select2-id="115">-12.00</option>
        <option value="-11.75" data-select2-id="116">-11.75</option>
        <option value="-11.50" data-select2-id="117">-11.50</option>
        <option value="-11.25" data-select2-id="118">-11.25</option>
        <option value="-11.00" data-select2-id="119">-11.00</option>
        <option value="-10.75" data-select2-id="120">-10.75</option>
        <option value="-10.50" data-select2-id="121">-10.50</option>
        <option value="-10.25" data-select2-id="122">-10.25</option>
        <option value="-10.00" data-select2-id="123">-10.00</option>
        <option value="-9.75" data-select2-id="124">-9.75</option>
        <option value="-9.50" data-select2-id="125">-9.50</option>
        <option value="-9.25" data-select2-id="126">-9.25</option>
        <option value="-9.00" data-select2-id="127">-9.00</option>
        <option value="-8.75" data-select2-id="128">-8.75</option>
        <option value="-8.50" data-select2-id="129">-8.50</option>
        <option value="-8.25" data-select2-id="130">-8.25</option>
        <option value="-8.00" data-select2-id="131">-8.00</option>
        <option value="-7.75" data-select2-id="132">-7.75</option>
        <option value="-7.50" data-select2-id="133">-7.50</option>
        <option value="-7.25" data-select2-id="134">-7.25</option>
        <option value="-7.00" data-select2-id="135">-7.00</option>
        <option value="-6.75" data-select2-id="136">-6.75</option>
        <option value="-6.50" data-select2-id="137">-6.50</option>
        <option value="-6.25" data-select2-id="138">-6.25</option>
        <option value="-6.00" data-select2-id="139">-6.00</option>
        <option value="-5.75" data-select2-id="140">-5.75</option>
        <option value="-5.50" data-select2-id="141">-5.50</option>
        <option value="-5.25" data-select2-id="142">-5.25</option>
        <option value="-5.00" data-select2-id="143">-5.00</option>
        <option value="-4.75" data-select2-id="144">-4.75</option>
        <option value="-4.50" data-select2-id="145">-4.50</option>
        <option value="-4.25" data-select2-id="146">-4.25</option>
        <option value="-4.00" data-select2-id="147">-4.00</option>
        <option value="-3.75" data-select2-id="148">-3.75</option>
        <option value="-3.50" data-select2-id="149">-3.50</option>
        <option value="-3.25" data-select2-id="150">-3.25</option>
        <option value="-3.00" data-select2-id="151">-3.00</option>
        <option value="-2.75" data-select2-id="152">-2.75</option>
        <option value="-2.50" data-select2-id="153">-2.50</option>
        <option value="-2.25" data-select2-id="154">-2.25</option>
        <option value="-2.00" data-select2-id="155">-2.00</option>
        <option value="-1.75" data-select2-id="156">-1.75</option>
        <option value="-1.50" data-select2-id="157">-1.50</option>
        <option value="-1.25" data-select2-id="158">-1.25</option>
        <option value="-1.00" data-select2-id="159">-1.00</option>
        <option value="-0.75" data-select2-id="160">-0.75</option>
        <option value="-0.50" data-select2-id="161">-0.50</option>
        <option value="-0.25" data-select2-id="162">-0.25</option>
        <option value="0.00" data-select2-id="163">0.00</option>
        <option value="+0.25" data-select2-id="164">+0.25</option>
        <option value="+0.50" data-select2-id="165">+0.50</option>
        <option value="+0.75" data-select2-id="166">+0.75</option>
        <option value="+1.00" data-select2-id="167">+1.00</option>
        <option value="+1.25" data-select2-id="168">+1.25</option>
        <option value="+1.50" data-select2-id="169">+1.50</option>
        <option value="+1.75" data-select2-id="170">+1.75</option>
        <option value="+2.00" data-select2-id="171">+2.00</option>
        <option value="+2.25" data-select2-id="172">+2.25</option>
        <option value="+2.50" data-select2-id="173">+2.50</option>
        <option value="+2.75" data-select2-id="174">+2.75</option>
        <option value="+3.00" data-select2-id="175">+3.00</option>
        <option value="+3.25" data-select2-id="176">+3.25</option>
        <option value="+3.50" data-select2-id="177">+3.50</option>
        <option value="+3.75" data-select2-id="178">+3.75</option>
        <option value="+4.00" data-select2-id="179">+4.00</option>
        <option value="+4.25" data-select2-id="180">+4.25</option>
        <option value="+4.50" data-select2-id="181">+4.50</option>
        <option value="+4.75" data-select2-id="182">+4.75</option>
        <option value="+5.00" data-select2-id="183">+5.00</option>
        <option value="+5.25" data-select2-id="184">+5.25</option>
        <option value="+5.50" data-select2-id="185">+5.50</option>
        <option value="+5.75" data-select2-id="186">+5.75</option>
        <option value="+6.00" data-select2-id="187">+6.00</option>
        <option value="+6.25" data-select2-id="188">+6.25</option>
        <option value="+6.50" data-select2-id="189">+6.50</option>
        <option value="+6.75" data-select2-id="190">+6.75</option>
        <option value="+7.00" data-select2-id="191">+7.00</option>
        <option value="+7.25" data-select2-id="192">+7.25</option>
        <option value="+7.50" data-select2-id="193">+7.50</option>
        <option value="+7.75" data-select2-id="194">+7.75</option>
        <option value="+8.00" data-select2-id="195">+8.00</option>
        <option value="+8.25" data-select2-id="196">+8.25</option>
        <option value="+8.50" data-select2-id="197">+8.50</option>
        <option value="+8.75" data-select2-id="198">+8.75</option>
        <option value="+9.00" data-select2-id="199">+9.00</option>
        <option value="+9.25" data-select2-id="200">+9.25</option>
        <option value="+9.50" data-select2-id="201">+9.50</option>
        <option value="+9.75" data-select2-id="202">+9.75</option>
        <option value="+10.00" data-select2-id="203">+10.00</option>
        <option value="+10.25" data-select2-id="204">+10.25</option>
        <option value="+10.50" data-select2-id="205">+10.50</option>
        <option value="+10.75" data-select2-id="206">+10.75</option>
        <option value="+11.00" data-select2-id="207">+11.00</option>
        <option value="+11.25" data-select2-id="208">+11.25</option>
        <option value="+11.50" data-select2-id="209">+11.50</option>
        <option value="+11.75" data-select2-id="210">+11.75</option>
        <option value="+12.00" data-select2-id="211">+12.00</option>
    </select>
```

The value 0 is actually significant  so i can't just default to zero

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `selected` attribute on the default option:

```
<option value="0.00" data-select2-id="163" selected>0.00</option>
```

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/hrj6mzga/

Comment: That would mean zero will always be selected but it has significance so i cant  default to it

Comment: Please explain more precisely what you would like to get